# Git-svn - determine branch being tracked?

Tags: git-svn

Is it possible to determine which branch (if any) is being tracked with git-svn? (in bash)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of all the Subversion branches using `git branch -r` (or, if there are multiple remotes, you may need to specify `git branch -r remotes/svn/*` or similar).

You can see which Subversion branch you're current branch is based on using `git svn dcommit --dry-run`. For example:

```
$ git svn dcommit --dry-run
Committing to http://path.to/repo/branches/branch_name
{possibly some hash details here}
```